# X,Y Coordinates Convert

Tags: python, math

I have written a program in which I am using pyautogui for autoclicking

My code

```
import pyautogui, time

time.sleep(5.5)
pyautogui.click(x=443, y=178)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

but the x, y coordinates which I am using are according to my monitor size which is 1920x1080

My Question:
The x, y coordinates are according to 1920x1080 I want to change them in 1280x720 so that it supports on any monitor resolution.
I wonder I can do that using numpy if yes then how?....if no then is there any other way to do it?....
Any help would be appreciated

Thank You

Regards

Comment: Scaling from 1920 to 1280 is easy in plain Python. `(x / 1920) * 1280`. But I suspect that's not what you're really after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
import pyautogui, time

xCoef = 1280/1920
yCoef = 720/1080


def clickFunc(x,y):
    pyautogui.click(x=int(xCoef*x), y=int(y*yCoef))


time.sleep(5.5)
clickFunc(443,178)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks bro I wasn't able to find out the maths behind it